# Export Image with attribute table in Google Earth Engine

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, night-time-images

I am quite new to Google Earth Engine.

I am trying to export a VIIRS night-time light image with an attribute table attached (displaying the mean, median etc) which is also clipped to India (I am using a shapefile). I am completely lost when it comes to exporting the image and attributes.

**Below is my code so far:**

```
var variable =  'NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMCFG';
var region = ee.FeatureCollection("users/user/india_adm").geometry();
var start_date = '2018-01-01';
var finish_date = '2018-12-31';
var bands = 'avg_rad';
var image = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMCFG');

// Load input imagery. NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMCFG
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection(variable)
                  .filterDate(start_date, finish_date)
                  .select(bands)
                  .filterBounds(region);

// Convert the layer
dataset = dataset.map(function(img){
  var date = img.get('system:time_start');
  return img.set('system_time_start', date);
});

// Create a function that takes an image, calculates the mean over a geometry and returns the value and the corresponding date as a feature.
var createData = function(img){
  var date = img.get('system_time_start');
  var valueMean = img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: region, scale: 30, maxPixels: 16016779});
  var valueSum = img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), geometry: region, scale: 30, maxPixels: 16016779});
  var valueMedian = img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.median(), geometry: region, scale: 30, maxPixels: 16016779});
  var valueStdDev = img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(), geometry: region, scale: 30, maxPixels: 16016779});
  var valueVariance = img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.variance(), geometry: region, scale: 30, maxPixels: 16016779});

  var ft = ee.Feature(null, {'system:time_start': date,
                             'date': ee.Date(date).format('Y/M/d'),
                             'Mean': valueMean.get('avg_rad'),
                             'Sum': valueSum.get('avg_rad'),
                             'Median': valueMedian.get('avg_rad'),
                             'stdDev': valueStdDev.get('avg_rad'),
                             'Variance': valueVariance.get('avg_rad'),
  });
  return ft;
};
// Apply the function to each image in dataset
var serie = dataset.map(createData);

var collection = ee.ImageCollection(variable)
                  .filterDate(start_date, finish_date)
                  .select(bands)
                  .filterBounds(region);
                  
var composite = collection.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());

var canny = ee.Algorithms.CannyEdgeDetector({
  image: composite, threshold: 100, sigma: 1
});

var nighttimeVis = {min: 0.0, max: 60.0};

print('composite', composite);

Map.setCenter(78.40263161385201, 21.17558399803013, 4.5);

Map.addLayer(composite.clip(region),{min:0,max:60.0,bands:"avg_rad_sum"});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably export the composite image as an image file and separately the table with information as e.g. a CSV file:

```
Export.table.toDrive({collection: serie, 
                      description: 'datatable', 
                      fileFormat: 'CSV'})
Export.image.toDrive({image: composite, 
                      description: 'exportImage', 
                      region: region, 
                      scale: 30,
                      maxPixels: 10e10})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! However, is it possible to adjust my export.table.toDrive to include a geometry column, so it is easier to import into ArcGIS?

Comment: You'd probably best export it as SHP file. Change 'CSV' to 'SHP'

Comment: Hi, i used 'SHP' and the export looked like it was downloading but this went on for over 4 hours so I think there is something wrong with my code as it should not be taking that long