# Can't generate a summary of a image based on a shapefile in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

You can skip many of my tries, I the fifth one is almost there:

I am trying to generate a series of summaries for an image collection, where I get the mean, median, 90th quantile and 10th quantile for a series of polygons. My goal is to export either a shapefile with the attributes of mean, median, etc. I loaded this [zipfile](https://github.com/derek-corcoran-barrios/EcosystemServicesCoastal/blob/master/Polygons.zip) as assets which you can find [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-my-derekcorcoran/assets/CitiesChile). This is what I have tried so far:

### First try (export to raster)

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_CO')
  .select('CO_column_number_density')
  .filterDate('2019-06-01', '2019-06-11');
// clip to an asset
var clip = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-my-derekcorcoran/assets/CitiesChile');
var clipped = collection.map(function(image) {  
    return image.clip(clip);
});


// get the mean of each feature in the collection   

var mean = clipped.map(function(image) {    
    return image.reduceRegions({
        collection: clip,
        reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
        scale: 500
    });
});     

// print the mean for each feature
print(mean);




//export the mean to a tif
Export.image.toDrive({
    image: mean,   
    description: 'meanCO',
    folder: 'EarthEngine',
    fileNamePrefix: 'meanCO',
    fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
    formatOptions: {
      cloudOptimized: true
    },
    skipEmptyTiles: true
});
```

This has seem to work until the last minute where it wont export it giving the following error:

```
ID: ZYUPAJJGL2U2PE4LLHGMXA5A
Phase: Failed
Runtime: 0s (started 2022-11-20 21:40:47 +0100)
Attempted 1 time
Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': Invalid type. Expected type: Image<unknown bands>. Actual type: FeatureCollection. (Error code: 3)
```

### Second try (export to shapefile)

Which led me to believe that this was generating a shapefile insted of a raster so I tried this:

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_CO')
  .select('CO_column_number_density')
  .filterDate('2019-06-01', '2019-06-11');
// clip to an asset
var clip = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-my-derekcorcoran/assets/CitiesChile');
var clipped = collection.map(function(image) {  
    return image.clip(clip);
});


// get the mean of each feature in the collection   

var mean = clipped.map(function(image) {    
    return image.reduceRegions({
        collection: clip,
        reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
        scale: 500
    });
});     

// print the mean for each feature
print(mean);




//export the mean to a shp
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: mean,   
    description: 'meanCO',
    folder: 'EarthEngine',
    fileNamePrefix: 'meanCO',
    fileFormat: 'SHP'
});
```

Which gave me the following error

```
Error: Unable to use a collection in an algorithm that requires a feature or image. This may happen when trying to use a collection of collections where a collection of features is expected; use flatten, or map a function to convert inner collections to features. Use clipToCollection (instead of clip) to clip an image to a collection. (Error code: 3)
```

### Third try (flatten)

Because of the error I tried flatten.

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_CO')
  .select('CO_column_number_density')
  .filterDate('2019-06-01', '2019-06-11');
// clip to an asset
var clip = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-my-derekcorcoran/assets/CitiesChile');
var clipped = collection.map(function(image) {  
    return image.clip(clip);
});


// get the mean of each feature in the collection   

var mean = clipped.map(function(image) {    
    return image.reduceRegions({
        collection: clip,
        reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
        scale: 500
    });
});     

// print the mean for each feature
print(mean);


var newTest =  mean.flatten()



//export the mean to a tif
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: newTest,   
    description: 'meanCO',
    folder: 'EarthEngine',
    fileNamePrefix: 'meanCO',
    fileFormat: 'SHP'
});
```

This again give me a new error:

```
Error: Shapefiles cannot contain multiple geometry types; found 'LineString', 'Polygon'. (Error code: 3)
```

But I know I loaded only polygons

### Fourth try (based on another question)

I found [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364779/export-image-with-attribute-table-in-google-earth-engine) so I tried to adapt it to my code, this is what I did:

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_CO')
  .select('CO_column_number_density')
  .filterDate('2019-06-01', '2019-06-15');
// clip to an asset
var clip = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-my-derekcorcoran/assets/CitiesChile');

var createData = function(img){
  var valueMean = img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: clip, scale: 30, maxPixels: 16016779});
  var valueMedian = img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.median(), geometry: clip, scale: 30, maxPixels: 16016779});
  var valueStdDev = img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(), geometry: clip, scale: 30, maxPixels: 16016779});
  var valueVariance = img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.variance(), geometry: clip, scale: 30, maxPixels: 16016779});

  var ft = ee.Feature(null, {'Mean': valueMean.get('CO_column_number_density'),
                             'Median': valueMedian.get('CO_column_number_density'),
                             'stdDev': valueStdDev.get('CO_column_number_density'),
                             'Variance': valueVariance.get('CO_column_number_density'),
  });
  return ft;
};
// Apply the function to each image in dataset
var serie = collection.map(createData);

Export.table.toDrive({collection: serie, 
                      folder: 'EarthEngine',
                      description: 'datatableCO', 
                      fileFormat: 'CSV'})
```

This runned for 9 hours and no results

### Fifth try:

this is almost there:

```js
// Composite an image collection and clip it to a boundary.

// Load Landsat 7 raw imagery and filter it to April-July 2000.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_CO')
  .select('CO_column_number_density')
  .filterDate('2019-06-01', '2019-12-12');

// Reduce the collection by taking the median.
var median = collection.median();

// Load a table of state boundaries and filter.
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-my-derekcorcoran/assets/CitiesChile');

// Clip to the output image to the Nevada and Arizona state boundaries.
var clipped = median.clipToCollection(fc);

// Display the result.
Map.centerObject(fc);
var band_viz = {
  min: 0,
  max: 0.03,
  palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};

Map.addLayer(clipped, band_viz, 'S5P N02');
```

I can see the mean, now what is left to do is to summarise to transform each raster into the polygons as a mean for each, and export as shapefiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this worked

```js
    
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_CO')
  .select('CO_column_number_density')
  .filterDate('2019-06-01', '2019-12-12');

// Reduce the collection by taking the median.
var median = collection.median();

// Load a table of state boundaries and filter.
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-my-derekcorcoran/assets/CitiesChile').filter(ee.Filter.or(
        ee.Filter.eq('Ciudad', 'antofagasta'),
        ee.Filter.eq('Ciudad', 'chicureo')));

Map.centerObject(fc);
var band_viz = {
  min: 0,
  max: 0.03,
  palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};

//Map.addLayer(median, band_viz, 'S5P N02');

var bscale = median.projection().nominalScale();
print('median scale:', bscale); 

print(median)

var cityCO = median.reduceRegions({
  collection: fc,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30 // the resolution of the GRIDMET dataset
});
print(cityCO);

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: cityCO,
  description: 'meanCO2',
  folder: 'EarthEngine',
  fileFormat: 'SHP'
});
```